# Get user inputs from the webcame for the game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, motion-detection

I'm creating a simple game using Unity Studio which uses arrow keys to move the player. Now what I want to do is, use webcam as a movement detecting device and track user's movements and move the player according to them. (For example, when user move his hand to right, webcam can track it and move the player to the right...)

So, is this possible ? If so, what are the techniques APIs I should use for this...?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at OpenCV, it is being used a lot in the field of body and head tracking, and there's a [unity plugin](https://github.com/hasanavi/OpenCV-Unity3D-Object-Tracking) which implements it that might be useful.

[Video Demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aE4_VtUDORw)

Answer (score 1):

It can't. But there is a lot of stuff out there on the internet.

[This](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/253706/hand-detection-using-web-cam-example) one has some interesting looking links.

[Emgu CV](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) looks interesting too.

There is some [JavaScript handtracking tool](https://code.google.com/p/js-handtracking/) too.

And of course there's kinect, but you need the 3d sensor.

You could also use [LeapMoution](https://www.leapmotion.com/).